# Commutative algebras whose bidual is commutative

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ultrafilters

Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $A$ a commutative $k$-algebra.  Call $D(A) := \mathrm{Hom}_k(A,k)$ the dual of $A$ as a $k$-module, and $DD(A) := \mathrm{Hom}_k(D(A),k)$ the dual of the latter.  Let $\Phi\colon A\to DD(A)$ be the canonical map $a \mapsto (u\mapsto u(a))$.

Define a multiplication on $DD(A)$ as follows: if $\xi,\eta \in DD(A)$, define $\xi\bullet\eta$ to be $D(A) \ni u \mapsto \eta(y\mapsto \xi(x\mapsto u(xy))) \in k$.  This is clearly $k$-bilinear, and furthermore $\Phi(a) \bullet \eta = \eta \bullet \Phi(a)$ is $u \mapsto \eta(y \mapsto u(ay))$ (for $a \in A$ and $\eta \in DD(A)$); in particular, $\Phi(a)\bullet\Phi(b) = \Phi(ab)$.  Clearly this is "the correct" multiplication on $DD(A)$.

I'm sure the following will come as a surprise to others as it did to me: *this product is not necessarily commutative*.  For a counterexample, consider $A = k[t]$ the ring of polynomials over a finite field $k$: then $D(A) = k^{\mathbb{N}}$ as a $k$-vector space, and $DD(A)$ contains at least the elements $\Lambda_{\mathscr{F}}\colon u \mapsto \lim_{\mathscr{F}} u$ where $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and their linear combinations (apparently these don't exhaust $DD(A)$: [see here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183537786); but this doesn't matter); now one can easily check that if $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ then $\Lambda_{\mathscr{F}} \bullet \Lambda_{\mathscr{G}} = \Lambda_{\mathscr{F}+\mathscr{G}}$ where $\mathscr{F}+\mathscr{G} = \{U \subseteq \mathbb{N} : \{j \in \mathbb{N} : U-j \in \mathscr{F}\} \in \mathscr{G}\}$ is the standard addition on $\beta\mathbb{N}$ defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) (§3.2 "Addition on the Stone–Čech compactification of the naturals") and which *is not commutative* (see, e.g., Hindman & Strauss, *Algebra in the Stone-Čech Compactification* (1998), §4.2).

So here's my question: **What nice conditions on the $k$-algebra $A$ guarantee that $DD(A)$ is commutative?**  I'm pretty sure that $A$ being finite (i.e., of finite type as a $k$-module) is sufficient, but even this I don't have an appropriate reference for (e.g.: in Vasconcelos, *Arithmetic of Blowup Algebras* (1994), prop. 1.1.15, the author does not bother to define the multiplication on $DD(A)$).

Contrariwise, does someone have a counterexample to $DD(A)$ being commutative that does not require ultrafilters or some use of the axiom of choice?

**Edit:** I believe the following gives a positive answer ($DD(A)$ is commutative) when $k$ is a noetherian integral domain and $A$ is a finite $k$-algebra.  Indeed, when $k$ is a noetherian integral domain with fraction field $F$, if $M$ is a $k$-module of finite type, then we can write a presentation $k^s \to k^r \to M \to 0$ (with $r,s$ natural numbers), and by comparing the obvious $0 \to D_k(M) \otimes_k F \to F^r \to F^s$ and $0 \to D_F(M \otimes_k F) \to F^r \to F^s$ (where $D_k(M) := \mathrm{Hom}_k(M,k)$ as a $k$-module), we see that the natural map $D_k(M) \otimes_k F \to D_F(M \otimes_k F)$ is an isomorphism — and also, $D_k(M)$ is a $k$-submodule of this.  Dualizing twice (and using the fact that $D_k(M)$ is a $k$-module of finite type, being a submodule of $k^r$), we see that $D_k D_k(M) \otimes_k F$ is isomorphic to $D_F D_F(M\otimes_k F) = M\otimes_k F$ (finite dimensional vector space over a field!), and $D_k D_k(M)$ is a $k$-submodule of it.  Now if $M = A$ is a finite $k$-algebra, one can check that the multiplication on $D_k D_k (A)$ is indeed the one obtained by restricting the multiplication on $D_F D_F(A\otimes_k F) = A\otimes_k F$ to it: but this multiplication is commutative.  So $D_k D_k (A)$ is a commutative $k$-algebra (indeed, a subalgebra of $A\otimes_k F$).

This is the case I was interested in, but I'm leaving the question open, since maybe someone can say something more general or more interesting about the question.

**Edit 2:** I'm told that the product I defined is known (at least in the context of normed algebras) as the [Arens multiplication](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Arens_multiplication) [note: the EoM article contains a number of typos / missing symbols: beware; [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-044-01/S0002-9939-1974-0341122-8/S0002-9939-1974-0341122-8.pdf) is another text defining the Arens product].  So my question could be rephrased as: "In the context of pure algebra, when is a commutative algebra Arens-regular?"

Comment: If I remember correctly, without AC it is possible that every vector space is reflexive that is $V\cong DD(V)$ via the canonical homomorphism. A choice-free counterexample would therefore have to be other a ring that is not a ring (and might not exist at all for all I know ...)

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I don't think it's possible for *every* vector space to be reflexive. If $V=\bigoplus k$ is a countable direct sum of one-dimensional spaces, and $V$ is reflexive, then the dual of $W=\prod k/\bigoplus k$ is zero, so $W$ is not reflexive. I'm not sure this invalidates your point, though.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Without some form of AC, $\prod k$ might be zero itself.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: OK, I meant each copy of $k$ to have a specified generator. In particular, if $U$ is the space of sequences of elements of the ground field, and $V$ the subspace of finite sequences, then not both $U$ and $U/V$ can be reflexive. Unless I'm being stupid?

Comment: Sorry, I mean not both $V$ and $U/V$ can be reflexive.

Comment: @Johannes: I don't understand: there are plenty of explicit nonzero elements in $\prod_{i\in I}k$ for any infinite set $I$, e.g., there is the diagonal embedding of $k$; there is the inclusion of $\bigoplus k$ which also contains plenty of explicit elements.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: I think that Johannes' point was that I wrote about a direct sum of one-dimensional spaces, without specifying that they came with simultaneous choices of isomorphisms with $k$. In that case, it's possible without choice that the quotient of the direct product by the direct sum (not the direct product itself) is zero, which would make my argument fail. But it's OK if I use a family of one-dimensional spaces furnished with isomorphisms with $k$.

Comment: I think that if one works without AC, it would be completely insane to denote by $\prod k$ a product of spaces each being isomorphic to $k$ (with no prescribed isomorphisms).

Comment: Had you had a look at the paper *On the second conjugate space of a Banach algebra as an algebra*, http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103037121, by Paul Civin and Bertram Yood. They seem to give a fairly detailed study of the question. In particular, they give conditions under which the analogue of this algebra (in the Banach category) is not commutative. (It is almost never.)

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but:

It shouldn't be surprising that this product isn't commutative: your definition has no obvious symmetry between $\xi$ and $\eta$, and so to me it's quite unclear that it's "the correct" multiplication on the double dual. Furthermore an attempt at a more symmetric construction fails. Namely, let's think about what happens when we dualize a multiplication $A \otimes A \to A$. We get a diagram

$$A^{\ast} \to (A \otimes A)^{\ast} \leftarrow A^{\ast} \otimes A^{\ast}$$

where the second arrow is not an isomorphism in general and hence is pointing in the wrong direction to give us a comultiplication on $A^{\ast}$. Dualizing a second time gives us a diagram

$$A^{\ast \ast} \leftarrow (A \otimes A)^{\ast \ast} \to (A^{\ast} \otimes A^{\ast})^{\ast} \leftarrow A^{\ast \ast} \otimes A^{\ast \ast}$$

where again the middle arrow is not an isomorphism in general and hence is pointing in the wrong direction to give us a multiplication on $A^{\ast \ast}$.

Comment: Yes, when I first tried to write a multiplication on the bi-dual (I was trying to work out an explicit example), I failed for the reason you point out. But once you demand that multiplication by $\Phi(a)$ should be the bi-transpose of multiplication by $a$, there's basically only one thing you can write down (maybe linear logicians could prove that it's unique in some deeper sense). And since it's simple enough, associative, and relates to $\Phi$ as one would like, I think I can safely say it's "the correct" formula. (Unless someone can suggest another one! :-)